# Python manage.py runserver admin page

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I am working on the django tutorial polls app. I have done all the other parts and now on the last bit of part 7, where I am modifying the admin page. I have all the codes as correctly undersigned from the documentation, but when I load the server admin page, from the terminal I can see that it breaks then I get the error this site can't be reached. I have really gone through every part of the coding and made comparisons, but everything seems fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
polls\urls.py

from django.urls import include, path

from . import views

`app_name = 'polls'

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('<int:pk>/detail/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
        path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ]
    
    
    site1\urls.py
    
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import include, path
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
    
    ]
```

Comment: Provide urls.py(app and project) code instead of an image

Comment: As I see from your images your pages are at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ and http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/

Answer (score 0):

Django is by default served on port 8000. Try to access address [127.0.0.1:8000](http://127.0.0.1:8000).